# using network plugins "cni": cni config unintialized; Skipping pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, cni

I created the [[image]kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes) cluster by using [kubeadm](/questions/tagged/kubeadm) `kubeadm init`.

I am getting error messages in `/var/log/messages`.

```
Oct 20 10:09:52 aws08 kubelet: I1020 10:09:52.015921    7116
docker_manager.go:1787] DNS ResolvConfPath exists:
/var/lib/docker/containers/717adf7a8481637ac20a9ba103d8f97635a88bf05f18bd4299f0d164e48f2920/resolv.conf.
Will attempt to add ndots option: options ndots:5 Oct 20 10:09:52
aws08 kubelet: I1020 10:09:52.015963    7116 docker_manager.go:2121]
Calling network plugin cni to setup pod for
kube-dns-2247936740-cjij4_kube-system(3b296413-96aa-11e6-8c40-02fff663a168)
Oct 20 10:09:52 aws08 kubelet: E1020 10:09:52.015982    7116
docker_manager.go:2127] Failed to setup network for pod
"kube-dns-2247936740-cjij4_kube-system(3b296413-96aa-11e6-8c40-02fff663a168)"
using network plugins "cni": cni config unintialized; Skipping pod Oct
20 10:09:52 aws08 kubelet: I1020 10:09:52.018824    7116
docker_manager.go:1492] Killing container
"717adf7a8481637ac20a9ba103d8f97635a88bf05f18bd4299f0d164e48f2920
kube-system/kube-dns-2247936740-cjij4" with 30 second grace period
```

The DNS pod is failing:

```
kube-system   kube-dns-2247936740-j5rtc        0/3       ContainerCreating   21         1h
```

If I disabled [CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni), the DNS pod is running. But the issue for DNS persists.

The method to disable cni is to comment the `KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS` line in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` and restart `kubelet` service

```
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --require-kubeconfig=true"
Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true"
# Environment="KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS=--network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin"
Environment="KUBELET_DNS_ARGS=--cluster-dns=100.64.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--v=4"
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

followed by:

sudo systemctl restart kubelet

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: it is on ec2. not sure whether it is related.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you forgot to [setup the pod network](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/#installing-a-pod-network).

From the documentation:

> It is necessary to do this before you try to deploy any applications to your cluster, and before `kube-dns` will start up. Note also that `kubeadm` only supports CNI based networks and therefore `kubenet` based networks will not work.

You can install a pod network add-on with the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f <add-on.yaml>
```

Example:

```
kubectl create -f https://git.io/weave-kube
```

To install [Weave Net](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kube-addon/) add-on.

After you have done this, you might need to recreate kube-dns pod.

Answer (score 0):

The cni intialization should be completed during kubelet initialization. So try reboot kubelet service and make sure that cni configuration can be parsed correctly.